# Steam controller not detected by steam

Tags: drivers, kernel, games, steam, gamepad

I am having trouble getting Steam to detect my Steam Controller. I can use the right pad to control the mouse and R to click in Ubuntu. In game I can press some buttons but they are not all set up correctly. I am would like to configure the controls within steam but it has no idea the controller exists.

I read that if you plug the controller in without batteries that steam will try to update the firmware but I was not prompted to do that neither on my Ubuntu computer or my brothers Windows laptop.

I have the snap version of Steam installed. [I got my udev rules form this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/2/1735465524711324558/) with my group set to my users. `KERNEL=="uinput", MODE="0660", GROUP="users", OPTIONS+="static_node=uinput"`. And I moved the 60-steam.rules so that they don't conflict with my 99-steam.rules.

Here are my steam controller settings:
[image]

Computer Information:

- Form Factor: Desktop
- Processor Information:

  - CPU Brand: AMD Ryzen 9 7900X 12-Core Processor
- Operating System Version:

  - Ubuntu 23.10
  - Kernel Version: 6.5.0-10-generic
  - X Window Manager: GNOME Shell 45
- Steam Runtime Version: steam-runtime_0.20231024.64411
- Video Card:

  - Driver: AMD GFX1100 (gfx1100, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.54, 6.5.0-10-generic)
- RAM: 63500 Mb